# Assign -1,0,1 to a number and multiple with its rank

Tags: r, sign, rank

This is my coding

```
no=10;mu<-10;sigma1<-1;dat <- matrix(rnorm(no, mu,sigma1), ncol = 5);dat
rnk=apply(dat,1,rank);rnk
diffe=apply(dat,1,function(x)x[]-mu);diffe
```

And i need to continue with...
if the `diffe` value is a positive number, assign 1 to that number, 0 for zero and -1 for a negative number as `sign`. After that, multiple 1/0/-1 with the respective number's rank as `SR`.
For example,

```
no=10;mu<-10;sigma1<-1;dat <- matrix(rnorm(no, mu,sigma1), ncol = 5);dat
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 10.514413 10.123087 8.768467 10.926197 9.818231
[2,]  9.048713  9.814045 10.00000  9.641175 9.500561

rnk=apply(dat,1,rank);rnk
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    1
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    5    3
[5,]    2    2

diffe=apply(dat,1,function(x)x[]-mu);diffe
[1,]  0.5144132 -0.9512866
[2,]  0.1230869 -0.1859549
[3,] -1.2315329  0.0000000
[4,]  0.9261974 -0.3588249
[5,] -0.1817694 -0.4994389

sign
[1,]  1 -1
[2,]  1 -1
[3,] -1  0
[4,]  1 -1
[5,] -1 -1
```

`SR` (rnk*sign)

1st number= 4*1+3*1+1*-1+5*1+2*-1 = 9

2nd number= 1*-1+4*-1+5*0+3*-1+2*-1 = -10

Thank you..=]]

Comment: Use the `sign()` function - it will generate the `sign` variable you describe perfectly. See `?sign` for details. Looks like you want `colSums(rnk * sign(diffe))`.

Comment: As a side not, a more common way to auto print an object than what you're doing `x=...;x` is to wrap it in parentheses. `(rnk = apply(dat, 1, rank))` will auto-print `rnk`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. these is what I need.. =]]